# Get all cell towers of a country from OpenCelliD database

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata, geocoding, apache-spark-sql

I have downloaded the dataset of [OpenCelliD](https://opencellid.org/downloads). It's a huge csv file with following fields:

radio, mcc, net, area, cell, unit, lon, lat, range, samples, changeable, created, updated, averageSignal

I want to get all the "cell towers of a specific country". One thing I understand that every country has their own 'mcc', for example [the mcc for Bangladesh is 470](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code#Bangladesh_-_BD).

I am using spark to analyse the data. My code is as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# create Spark context with Spark configuration
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Opencellid country filter")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("cell_towers.csv")

mapped_data = df.where(df['mcc'] == '470').collect()

fp = open("cell_tower_output.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(fp, dialect="excel")
writer.writerows(mapped_data)
fp.close()
```

I have got 199K+ rows for one specific county(by filtering the mcc) I am searching for. Is it possible to have more than 199k+ cell towers in a country? Am I doing something wrong in the spark code?

Comment: It might be useful to try grouping and counting by country first (`df.groupBy('mcc').count()`) then checking to see if 199k is plausible for Bangladesh compared to other countries. Are any of those fields useful for checking for duplicate records?

Comment: [This page](https://www.quora.com/How-many-cell-towers-exist-worldwide-Can-you-point-me-to-any-resources-that-allow-one-to-see-cell-towers-by-country-worldwide) suggests that there are a few million worldwide, which does make 200k for Bangladesh seem like a lot. (Also, you totally do not need Spark to wrangle a few million rows - Python and R would be fine if you have enough RAM, or you could pre-filter the CSV with a tool like awk)

Comment: I have tried with two other countries, they have more or less same number of rows.

Comment: This is what spark gives me for `df.groupBy('mcc').count().show()`


                                                                 
|mcc|  count|
|470| 139532|

Comment: Those are the results I get in R, too. That puts Bangladesh at about the 76th percentile for number of records (seems too high), but only about 3% of the largest MCC (seems reasonable). So - I think your Spark code is correct, but there's probably more to learn about this dataset.

Comment: (I see now that Bangladesh is the 8th most populous country in the world, so maybe being at the 76th percentile isn't so unusual after all)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I have done some research and found that my code is giving right number of rows.